# Correct user name doesn't display

Tags: support, chat

I changed my User name to 'United' and then finally 'Tyto alba'. It is the latter now, on every profile. But in chatroom it still displays the former.

Is it a bug or the chatroom is not updated as fast as the main site?

Here's a snip off (taken 6 mins earlier):

[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Citation needed* of course, but the nicknames and avatars on chat are cached for a while and it takes a while to update, anecdotally speaking. To double the fun, I suspect it also has some delays client side so different people see the nicknames at different times.

So yeah, chances are it'll fix itself after a while

(Failing which, get a mod to refresh it. Which seems to have worked. I kinda forgot about that)

Comment: It shows the correct name now.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up manually syncing it for you.